# Visual Studio Code Live Server: Not Works For Index.html using iframe tag

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, iframe

have a problem with Live Server Updating Index.html ...

It's works when i doing manually save...  working with big project, and manually update every time page is too stupid deal

in Index.html I using Iframe to navigation.html ..

pay attention when i updating navigation.html it's working , updating ...

but when i trying to update index.html .. unfortunately ...

Here Is :::

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Pam  dasd adsadsa dasdsa </h1>
    <iframe 1 src ="navigation.html" linkTarget = "iframe2">
    <iframe2>
</body>
</html>
```

**navigation.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>agent 1 link</li>
        <li>agent 2 link</li>
        <li>agent 3 link</li>
        <li>agent 4 link</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**PS :** Help -> Toggle Developer Tool , showing no errors, all working ok. i mean : `[Extension Host] Change detected`

Here is Repo:::

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2jze.png)

Maybe that it extension bug ? :)

**PS:::**

***!!!Attention!!!***

**Without iframe tag Index.html .. Live is working well .**

**But i need iframe.**

Answer (score 0):

Is your `index.html` inside of a folder preceded by a period?

Does your domain look like this? `http://127.0.0.1:5500/.folder/index.html`

Comment: yes i'm sorry .. i'm using them in parent(same) folder

Comment: In settings search for "useWebExt" and make sure that isn't checked.

Comment: is unchecked, i need check it ?

Comment: Nope, leave it unchecked.     
There's no special characters in your folder paths at all?

No adblocker in your browser?

Comment: Does it work if you manually save the file?

Comment: problem is with iframe ... after i removing it .. Live in index.html working well

Comment: No i don't using adblocker  ... Live not working on Safari / Chrome  or any other web

Comment: Yes Sir, it works when i manually Save this file .

Comment: I don't typically use autosave because it causes a lot of issues with React and Node when working in the files. But if you have to use auto save you can go in and set a delay and make the delay something like 1-3 seconds. 

Alternatively, what I prefer, is enabling Format on Save and that re-aligns all my code for me in a nice way and I just got in the habit of hitting CMD/CTRL+S

Comment: my autosave is turned off... i usually same like CTRL + S ... What about CMD ? how you using it ?

Comment: CMD is for Mac. I was just trying to be inclusive.